# Delete empty series of data from xy plot VBA

Tags: excel, vba, series

I have a vba code which adds series of data row by row based on the total number of rows of data. Based on a minimum value in one column of data, two charts are created. My skills in vba are very basic.

When I run the code, the graphs are produced but the first graph has many empty series of data added. I am unsure why this is and want to either delete them after production or stop them being added in the first place.

```
Sub Button6_Click()

Dim xrng As Range
Dim yrng As Range
Dim x2rng As Range
Dim y2rng As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim Rng As Range
Dim l As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim i2 As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Worksheets("Template").Activate

Dim lv As String
    lv = Worksheets("Template").Range(Worksheets("Template").Range("B11"), Worksheets("Template").Range("B11").End(xlDown)).Find(WorksheetFunction.Small(Worksheets("Template").Range(Worksheets("Template").Range("B11"), Worksheets("Template").Range("B11").End(xlDown)), 1), , , 1).Address
    Range(lv).Select
l = ActiveCell.Row

k = Worksheets("Template").Range(Worksheets("Template").Range("B11"), Worksheets("Template").Range("B11").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

c = l - 10

i = 1
i2 = 1
j = 1

Set xrng = Worksheets("Template").Range("C11:CP11")
Set yrng = Worksheets("Template").Range("C201:CP201")
Set x2rng = xrng.Offset(1, 0)
Set y2rng = yrng.Offset(1, 0)

Dim DownSweep As Chart
    Set DownSweep = Charts.Add

With DownSweep
        DownSweep.ChartType = xlXYScatter
        DownSweep.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        DownSweep.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = xrng
        DownSweep.SeriesCollection(1).Values = yrng
End With

i = i + 1

ITERATE:

If i < c Then

DownSweep.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
DownSweep.SeriesCollection(i).XValues = x2rng
DownSweep.SeriesCollection(i).Values = y2rng
Set x2rng = x2rng.Offset(1, 0)
Set y2rng = y2rng.Offset(1, 0)
i = i + 1
GoTo ITERATE

Else

End If

If i < k Then

Dim UpSweep As Chart
    Set UpSweep = Charts.Add

With UpSweep
    UpSweep.ChartType = xlXYScatter
    UpSweep.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    UpSweep.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = x2rng
    UpSweep.SeriesCollection(1).Values = y2rng
End With

End If

i = i + 1
i2 = i2 + 1

ITERATE2:

If i < k Then

UpSweep.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
UpSweep.SeriesCollection(i2).XValues = x2rng
UpSweep.SeriesCollection(i2).Values = y2rng
Set x2rng = x2rng.Offset(1, 0)
Set y2rng = y2rng.Offset(1, 0)
i = i + 1
i2 = i2 + 1
GoTo ITERATE2

Else

End If

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Judoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but this should be easier to work with:

```
Sub Button6_Click()

    Dim xrng As Range, yrng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim l As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim i2 As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim DownSweep As Chart, UpSweep As Chart, cht As Chart
    Dim ws As Worksheet, smallest

    Set ws = Worksheets("Template") '<< use variables for worksheets!

    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Range("B11"), ws.Range("B11").End(xlDown))

    smallest = WorksheetFunction.Small(rng, 1)
    l = rng.Find(what:=smallest, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Row
    k = rng.Rows.Count

    c = l - 10

    Set xrng = ws.Range("C11:CP11")
    Set yrng = ws.Range("C201:CP201")

    Set DownSweep = Charts.Add
    DownSweep.ChartType = xlXYScatter

    Set UpSweep = Charts.Add
    UpSweep.ChartType = xlXYScatter

    For i = 1 To k
        Set cht = IIf(i <= c, DownSweep, UpSweep) 'which chart to add to ?
        With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries()
            .XValues = xrng.Offset(i - 1, 0).Value
            .Values = yrng.Offset(i - 1, 0).Value
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

EDIT:  This, using `IIf()`

```
Set cht = IIf(i <= c, DownSweep, UpSweep)
```

is the same as

```
If i <= c Then
    Set cht = DownSweep
Else
    Set cht = UpSweep
End If
```

Comment: Incredible! Thank you so much. The For loop at the end, I don't fully understand it. What is the "IIF"?

Comment: See my edit above and also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/iif-function  It's just deciding which chart to add the series to.